# Linux shell ^C does not work

Tags: linux, bash

I upgraded my linux mint 14 and my bash began to do strange things. When I start a terminal ^C, ^Z doesn't work but when I do "sudo su - myuser" it works. I have no idea where to begin to find what is wrong.

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 57; columns 237; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke

$ bind -v
set bind-tty-special-chars on
set blink-matching-paren on
set byte-oriented off
set completion-ignore-case off
set completion-map-case off
set convert-meta off
set disable-completion off
set echo-control-characters on
set enable-keypad off
set enable-meta-key on
set expand-tilde off
set history-preserve-point off
set horizontal-scroll-mode off
set input-meta on
set mark-directories on
set mark-modified-lines off
set mark-symlinked-directories off
set match-hidden-files on
set menu-complete-display-prefix off
set meta-flag on
set output-meta on
set page-completions on
set prefer-visible-bell on
set print-completions-horizontally off
set revert-all-at-newline off
set show-all-if-ambiguous off
set show-all-if-unmodified off
set skip-completed-text off
set visible-stats off
set bell-style audible
set comment-begin #
set completion-display-width -1
set completion-prefix-display-length 0
set completion-query-items 100
set editing-mode emacs
set history-size 500
set keymap emacs
```

Something new I've found: Banshee doesn't work either.
There must be something with bash but no idea...

I tried bash --noprofile --norc but no luck.

It's very annoying...

Any idea?

Comment: You could try running `trap` and see whether there's a trap on SIGINT, I suppose, but it seems rather unlikely.  You might try `trap '' 2` to ignore interrupts, and then `trap 2` ro reset to default. If for some reason your shell is inheriting SUG_IGN for SIGINT, there's a chance this won't help. You might need to write some C code to determine whether any signals are ignored. I'm dubious about all this -- it doesn't feel plausible. But it is an avenue to investigate. If you shell is started ignoring interrupts, that would explain why it ignores them. Why it is running like that is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but no trap.

Comment: test with different terminal programs. How is the behavior without graphical mode - pure console?

Comment: xterm, aterm, gnome-terminal no luck. pure console works as intended

Comment: New thing: it works with metacity. It doesn't with cinnamon.

Comment: I am suffering a very similar fate. I am using Gentoo Linux. I just did some more experiment with different terminals. If I start with xterm, or lxterminal, it works. However, if I start gnome-terminal with xterm, it will not work. Then from the gnome-terminal, if I start another xterm, the xterm #2 will not respond to ^C! Interesting eh? So, for my case, it seems like gnome-terminal is at fault though I have no idea how.

Comment: I gave up and reinstalled the OS.